# Why my selecting options are not showing in html?

Tags: html

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
    <div id="border"></div>
    <div>Currency Exchange</div>
    <input type="text" id="output">
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div>
      <label for="amount">Amount</label>
      <input type="number" id="amount" class="output" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="third">
    <div>
      <label for="from">From</label>
      <select id="from" name="from">
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
        <option value="AFN">AFN</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am try to show the options for the currencies in the select tag but i don't know why it is     not showing up i also tried changing the color of select as black but that didn't help please
someone tell how to deal with this problem

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it's not in the code you posted. I put it in a stack snippet and the options show up just fine.

Comment: You don't have any code to make it dynamic. Maybe you need a Javascript code to make what you want.